# Visual Studio 2010 does not stop on breakpoint when debugging C# COMVisible class methods

Tags: .net, visual-studio, com, debugging, breakpoints

I'm working on C# COM component. This component is called from application plugin and when I manually attach debugger to the application, it stops on breakpoints. But when I use Visual Studio debug command (F5 key) and specify "Start external program" in project debugger settings, Visual Studio does not stop on breakpoints.

In short:
* set breakpoint, compile, start app, attach debugger to debug "Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0) code", exec plugin method - VS stops on breakpoint.
* set breakpoint, specify Start external program, press F5 - application starts, exec plugin method - VS skips breakpoint. "Attach To..." command shows ProteusDebugEngine instead of some kind of managed code.

Comment: Check this: http://vvvv.org/forum/plugin-debugging-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the debugger cannot figure out which of its two engines to use because the application that is starting is not a managed one. So it defaults to the 4.0 engine. You have to tell the debugger that you want a different engine by explicitly telling it what runtime is being used.

Create or edit a config file for the application that you are wanting to debug and add a SupportedRuntime element to it.

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
  <startup>        
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.[version on your machine]" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

See [MSDN blog entry](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CsupportedRuntime%20version=%22v2.0.%5Bversion%20on%20your%20machine%5D%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/startup%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/configuration%3E).